# Unable to open a file using wild card through VBA, there will be only 1 file with that file name with changing dates

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a file "Account Master mmddyy.xls" which gets saved at a particular path, every month only date and month changes. How can I open the file with wild card using "Account Master" as that will be consistent. Only 1 file will be saved at this location with similar file name.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
Sub open_file()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\WORK\Account Master*"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub open_file()
Dim sFilename As String
    sFilename = Dir("C:\Users\Desktop\WORK\Account Master*", vbArchive)
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFilename
end sub
```

Comment: This didn't work but I found another similar way to do it using below code, thanks for your help!   Sub open_file2()

Dim sFilename As String

    sFilename = Dir("C:\Users\\Desktop\WORK\Account Master*")
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Desktop\WORK\" & sFilename
    MsgBox sFilename & " is open"